# Triggering of pageload event

Tags: asp.net

I have  different events such as checkbox changed event , linkbutton clicked event,etc,. On clicking any of these, the page load event also triggers along with the triggered event. I don't want the triggering of the page load event  when I trigger other events.  Help me to prevent triggering of page load event on triggering other events.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the Page Load event is always going to fire. This is because the Page is loading up on the server side. It's part of the the ASP.NET page life cycle.

However, if there's something that you want to run in your Page Load event when the page is hit for the first time, but not any other time after than, you can wrap this functionality in an If statement, using the Page.IsPostback property.  The IsPostback property will be false when you hit the page for the first time, but will be true when any of your buttons, links, etc cause a postback.

Example, if VB.NET

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
' Code that is to be executed when the page is first hit goes here
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the code in the page_load() inside the 'isPostBack' check.

Example in C#

```
protected void page_load()

{

if(!isPostBack)

{

.........//Your

.........//code here

}

}
```

And of course write the code that you want to execute, when the event gets triggered, inside the event 'Click' of the respective control.
Hope that helps.